# node not installing forever -g

Tags: javascript, node.js

forever is not installing globally in mac 
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-166 database]$ npm install forever -g
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/ec2-user/.npm/forever/0.15.2/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.19-29.55.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/quickstart-nodejs-master/database/npm-debug.log

Comment: You may better want to checkout [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Answer (score 0):

> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

You need to run this command as an administrator, try `sudo npm i forever -g` and enter your password when prompted.

Comment: tried..but not installing . is there any other best way to run continuous background Job with Node JS even i shutdown my mac ..